# The Union of $n$ Independent Events Equals the Complement of the Complement of Their Product

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

**The Statement of the Problem:**

If the events $A_1,...,A_n$ are independent, show that

$$ P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right) = 1-\prod_{i=1}^n P(A_i^c) .$$

**Where I Am:**

So, I've seen this equality stated before, but it doesn't actually make sense to me for the following reason:

$$ P\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n A_i \right)= P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^c \right) \text{(by De Morgan's Laws) and}$$

$$ P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^n A_i^c \right) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(A_i^c) $$

...rather than the complement of the products of these independent events.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You've made in error in using DeMorgan's law. Specifically,

$$\bigcup_{i = 1}^n A_i = \left(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n A_i^c\right)^{\color{red}{c}}.$$

Comment: Ah. Yes, of course. Thank you!